# Circular shifting in C, unexpected behavior

Tags: c, bit-shift, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm currently doing an exercise from The C Programming Language (K&R) [exercise 2.8] to write a right circular shift function to rotate an integer x, n places.

I believe I have come up with a solution, but for some strange reason, when I shift beyond the word length, (ie. a 100 place shift), I am still getting the correct answer when I believe I shouldn't with the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned rightrot(unsigned x, int n);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", rightrot(1,100));  /* this should yield zero (overshift) */
    return 0;
}

unsigned rightrot(unsigned int x, int n)
{
    unsigned a = ~0;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; a > 1; ++i)     /* calculating the word length */
        a = a/2;

    return (x >> n) | (x << (i-n));
}
```

The shifts on the line:

```
return (x >> n) | (x << (i-n));
```

should shift all of the binary digits out at leave `0 | 0` I would have thought, when passed a shift size larger than the word length. But to my surprise this code returns exactly the same answers as if I was to use the following version that allows for n larger than the word length:

```
return (x >> (n % i)) | (x << ((i-n) % i);
```

remembering that `i` is the word length.

I am using gcc 4.7.2 with -std=c89 and -pedantic-errors, and get no warnings either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shifting by more than the wordsize in C in UNDEFINED, so anything might happen.  On most machines, shifts are done with a mux-tree with log<sub>2</sub>wordsize select bits, disregarding the higher bits of the shift count, so a shift of 100 on a 32-bit machine is likely to be the same as a shift of 4.  But you might get anything, including a crash.

Comment: Fun historic bit: back when the 80x86 did not have a barrel/funnel shifter, shifting a 16-bit int left or right more than 16 bits gave you all-zero or all-1 values (depending on signedness of shift).  When they added the fast shift hardware, so that it did not have to use a microcode loop, it started shifting mod word-size.

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is greater than `i`, then `i - n` is negative. Using the `<<` operator with a negative number as the right operand is undefined behavior.

Comment: I think this might be how I should have done it: `return (x >> (n % i)) | (x << (i - (n % i)))` Would you agree?